# MeteorJs - Error in an http call

Tags: javascript, meteor, github-api

This is my first Meteor program and I'm trying to make an http call to Github. I'm facing an error which goes like this:

> Exception in delivering result of invoking 'getUserInfo': ["click button"]/<@http://localhost:3000/helloMeteor.js?823f404b37c246a7d23ae50a10c37969e426b2b8:18:17
>   Meteor.bindEnvironment/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf:983:17
>   ._maybeInvokeCallback@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:3860:7
>   .receiveResult@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:3880:5
>   ._livedata_result@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:4964:7
>   Connection/onMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:3725:7
>   ._launchConnection/self.socket.onmessage/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:2717:11
>   _.forEach@http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:156:7
>   ._launchConnection/self.socket.onmessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:2716:9
>   SockJShttp://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:156:9
>   SockJShttp://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:1141:5
>   SockJShttp://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:1199:13
>   SockJShttp://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:1346:9

Here is my code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
// counter starts at 0
Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

Template.hello.helpers({
    counter: function () {
        return Session.get('counter');
    }
});

//This is how you bind event handlers
//Format: eventtype selector
Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
        // increment the counter when button is clicked
        Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
        Meteor.call('getUserInfo', 'rutwick', function(err, res) {
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
});
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
//Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    Meteor.methods({
        getUserInfo: function(userN) {
            var github = new GitHub({
                version: "3.0.0", // required
                timeout: 5000     // optional
            });

            var result = github.user.getFollowingFromUser({
                user: userN
            });

            return result;
        }
    });
//});
}
```

I am using the Github API JavaScript wrapper. Even if I try to make the call using simple HTTP, I still get the error.

What exactly needs to be done to solve this?

***Update***
Here is the server log:

> Exception while invoking method 'getUserInfo' ReferenceError: GitHub is not defined
>   I20150429-19:22:53.064(5.5)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.getUserInfo (app/helloMeteor.js:29:34)
>   I20150429-19:22:53.064(5.5)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
>   I20150429-19:22:53.064(5.5)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648:1
>   I20150429-19:22:53.064(5.5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
>   I20150429-19:22:53.064(5.5)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:647:1
>   I20150429-19:22:53.064(5.5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
>   I20150429-19:22:53.064(5.5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:646:1)
>   I20150429-19:22:53.064(5.5)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:546:1

Comment: Can we have the Chrome console output (it's way better), and if it applies, the server log too?

Comment: Aha, the server log. I did not know there is a server log. The output I have posted is from FireBug's console. Updating my question with the server log.

Comment: No worries :) Only show server log if it applies. But I cannot stress enough on using Chrome *at least* to view console logs, the other consoles just spit out nonsense... for Meteor at least.

Comment: Added the server log, Github is not defined it seems. I installed from here: https://github.com/michael/github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I advise you to install [this lovely package](https://atmospherejs.com/bruz/github-api):

```
meteor add bruz:github-api
```

It should allow you to use Github API on the server side, according to the example on the web page I linked to.

**After-chat edit:** So far the readme of this package is outdated. To use this package like shown in the example, you need to call this instead of `require("github")`:

```
Npm.require('github-api');
```

Then the rest of the example *should* be fine. Should make a pull request soon to ask for an update.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but my server log shows something else. And fixing this gives me undefined.

Comment: I think I need to require the github package. I tried `require` but now the server says `require` is undefined.

Comment: My guess is, call `require` after installing the package like they do, even if it seems dubious... or try using the GitHub object, maybe the package installation defines it in your project.

Comment: Tried that one, I still get `require` as undefined!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76547/discussion-between-rutwick-gangurde-and-bravekenny).

Comment: As a followup to the story, [a pull request](https://github.com/bruz/meteor-github-api/pull/2) was submitted to the package's maintainer.

Comment: Aha... thanks a lot! That should help others who use the package in the future.